# Call Delphi DCOM

Tags: delphi, call, dcom

I am totally new to Delphi and DCOM. I was assigned the task of modifying the old Delphi project. I am able to make the change and build .exe. I am using Delphi 7 IDE.

For some reason, we need the old version and the new one running on the same server at the same time.

What I did is, built the new version, let's call it `delphiapp_original.exe`, renamed it to `delphiapp_new.exe`. The way we run the application is like:

```
callerapp delphiapp_original.ObjA
```

`callerapp` is another application who calls Delphi DCOM objects.

My question is how to run my new Delphi application. Is it:

```
callerapp delphiapp_new.ObjA
```

I know my question sounds stupid, but I don't have environment to test so I am not able to try the command. Another reason I am asking is that I am not sure if `delphiapp_original` or `delphiapp_new` in the above command line are the name of the exe or the name of some class/object inside the exe. It would be good if they are the name of the exe, thus different DCOM objects will be called. But if `delphiapp_original` or `delphiapp_new` in the above command line are the name of the class/object inside the exe, that would cause trouble since I only renamed the exe, all the things inside the old exe and new exe remain the same name, I won't know which object is called.

Comment: You are not going to succeed if you can't test this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, it is not enough to just rename the EXE file.  You have to edit the project's Type Library to change the GUID(s)/ProgID(s) of the COM object(s) that it defines.  Then you can compile a new version of the EXE file and run it so its COM objects get re-registered using their new GUID(s)/ProgID(s).  Then, the old and new versions will be able to co-exist on the same PC as different names.